# ASP.net Repeater -- setting N Maximum Repetitions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, repeater

I am using a Repeater control to display data from a SQL server on multiple different sites right now.  I am wondering if there is any way to *make a repeater only "repeat" or run through its cycles a maximum of N times.*

I split a Div element up into 4 equal sections which have just enough room for 4 cycles of this repeater.  If it runs more than 4 times, it pushes everything down in the div and begins a new row of images/text I would prefer to avoid.  It makes the web page look uglier and does not really accomplish much for the client.

Also is there any way to **randomly select** which iterations through the repeater get displayed?  For example, one time the page loads, the repeater pulls iterations 2-5, then you refresh the page and the repeater pulls iterations 1-4.  That would be very cool if I could make the images/text that show up to be random.

For those that are curious, a repeater is an ASP.net object which basically iteratively displays or otherwise works with data from a table, SQL database, etc.  It just goes row by row through whatever the data is.

Comment: I assume this is is data-bound? This kind of limitation should be implemented in your data source... (otherwise you're looking at `class CustomRepeater : Repeater`)

Comment: It would be better to limit the record count of the data source instead of limiting the number of iterations the repeater performs before stopping.  Depending on what your data source is, you can use LINQ functions .Skip() and .Take().

Comment: So you are recommending I simply change my SQL queries to pull back only the first 4... this is an approach as well although I would like to grab all of them, so I can work on making it randomly select which data is being displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than try to do anything funky with the repeater, you can do this to your data source itself before binding it to your repeater.

For example:

```
var rand = new Random();
var myCollection = GetSomethingFromSomewhere();
myRepeater.DataSource = myCollection
    .OrderBy(x => rand.Next())
    .Take(4);
myRepeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: Interesting... I'm not sure what this syntax is doing here but I see what you are getting at, doing it in the code behind was my first thought as well perhaps truncating the Datasource to maximum of 4 elements.

Comment: If you're not using code-behind, then as you commented above, you can adjust the SQL statement to accomplish the same thing, with a `TOP 4` and an `ORDER BY` which randomizes it.

Comment: If you're not familiar with LINQ, it's just a faster way to deal with collections in .NET (3.5 and above). `OrderBy` will take a collection and sort it by some parameter (or in this case, a random number). `Take` retrieves the top N (4) records from the collection.

Comment: I am using code behind so I think this is the best answer here, thanks all it was very helpful.  will post results eventually

Comment: Any working results or code for this issue, i am having the same problem?