# Limit asp.repater to bind first two rows only

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I want to display top 3 products in featured table on my web page from the same datasource which is pulling all rows from SQL and then all rows can be find in another asp.net repeater. How can i limit

**ASP.net**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="FeaturedProduct" runat="server">
                              <ItemTemplate>
                                  <tr>
<td><%# Eval("ProductName")%></td>
<td><%# Eval("Price")%></td>
</tr>
                              </ItemTemplate>
                          </asp:Repeater>
```

**SQL Data Source**

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource DataSourceMode="DataSet" ID="ProductPics" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PIConnectionString1 %>" 
    SelectCommand="Select ProductName, Price from Products where ProdImageId = @ProdId">
    <SelectParameters>                     
    <asp:RouteParameter Name="ProdId" DbType="Int32" RouteKey="ProdId" />
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource >
```

**C#**

```
FeaturedProduct.DataSourceID = "PriceComparison";
```

**Update**
I am done with the limit datasouce for top 3 rows only, But now eval bind is not working. So how can i bind the data with element in html.

```
var mycollection = ProductPics.SelectCommand;
FeaturedProduct.DataSource = mycollection.Take(3);
FeaturedProduct.DataBind();
```

Comment: Which database system are we talking about?

Comment: SQL Server 2008. Alex

Comment: So Alex, I want to bind tow html table with same data source and wanted to display 2-3 records on table above the fold as featured and a link with see all(which will point to another table having all rows) below the fold of webpage.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that using a data source twice will lead to two requests to the database. You have considered that?

Comment: var mycollection = ProductPics.SelectCommand;
FeaturedProduct.DataSource = mycollection.Take(3);
FeaturedProduct.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ProdImageId` is primary contraint in you table, put below sql query as select command :-

```
SelectCommand="Select top 3 ProductName, Price from Products where ProdImageId = @ProdId order by ProdImageId desc"
```

Comment: Ashok, I know about this. But this will force me to add 2 sql command on the same page. One for top 3 and another for all rows. Because i have two table in my web page and want to bind one with top 2-3(as featured) and one with all rows.

Comment: you want to bind both tables with same data source ?

Comment: Yes. I want to bind both table with same data source and wanted to display 2-3 records on table on top of page as featured and a link with see all(which will point to another table having all rows)

Comment: I saw something here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955743/asp-net-repeater-setting-n-maximum-repetitions but not sure how to implement with my code, and how it will work, Any suggestion?

Comment: i think the best possible way to limit the rows is configuring your select query in data source rather then playing with the GridView.

Comment: I think that will not be an good idea for performance. As i am going to run the same query twice to pull the same data. Once for 3 records and again for all records.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ROW_NUMBER`-argument to your `WHERE`-clause, and with an additional parameter call the data source with either three or all records.
Use the events of the DataSource object to manipulate the parameter as you need it.

Comment: Can't we do in C# code behind, as i already done to bind top 3 records in featured repeater (SEE Update in question) and then i can bind another repater to main datasource.

Comment: So now top 3 records are in MYCOLLECTION Variable. And my question is how can i populate that records in HTML, since eval is not working now.

Answer (score 0):

The DataSource-property `SelectCommand` is a String, containing your SQL-Select statement. `Take` is a String-Extension, returning the first three characters of the String.

In other words, your code does not query the database and does not return a set of records.

Comment: The ones from my previous answer.